# Basic Structure of a Haskell Program

Tags: function, haskell, data-structures, subroutine

Many of the Haskell tutorials I've looked through focus almost entirely on syntax with very little coverage on how to structure a program.

For example...

Here's a bare-bones outline of a C++ application:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int addition (int a, int b)
{
  int r;
  r=a+b;
  return (r);
}

int main ()
{
  int z;
  z = addition (5,3);
  cout << "The result is " << z;
  return 0;
}
```

When I first started learning C++, examples like these helped me immensely in learning how to assemble individual pieces into working programs. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong places, but I haven't been able to find any such examples that are as direct and simple for Haskell.

I already know A LOT of Haskell syntax. I can write recursive list comprehensions, and manipulate strings, integers, and lists out the wazoo.

**In short:** I just want to know what two subroutines and variable pass looks like in Haskell. If I can get some basic understanding on how to structure a Haskell program, I might finally be able to put all the syntax I've learned to some use.

Comment: I'd start at places like http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_in_5_steps I'm learning Clojure. However, I do have the O'Reilly Haskell book, and this book -- http://www.nostarch.com/lyah.htm -- seems to be getting a lot of good reviews.

Comment: While this is a legitimate question, allow me to suggest that you are approaching Haskell slightly wrong. Haskell emphasizes pure functions as much as possible, and most Haskell implementations provide a REPL (read-eval-print loop) where you can play around with functions you have defined. I highly recommend, instead of making small programs that print to stdout, just write functions and play with them in ghci. I think you'll find it's much more flexible and fun for learning Haskell.

Comment: @DanBurton I've probably spent the last month reading up on syntax, and playing around with functions and list comprehensions in ghci. I'm ready to make a program now. (:D You're right in that I have been approaching Haskell wrong. I'm trying to apply procedural programming principles to a functional programming language. I'm still trying to wrap my head around how to turn a bunch of functions into something that can do more than run once and stop. I'll keep reading.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus This is my first time seeing the Haskell in 5 Steps link. From what I gather, I can make a Haskell program by having main call and loop through various functions listed beneath it?

Comment: I don;t know Haskell, but it is -- from what I have heard a difficult language to learn. I started diving into Clojure, but there is a lot more to learn than the syntax. Suggest learning Haskell might require the same treatment, hence the link to that book and the Haskell Wiki.

Comment: @SubtleArray: there's no "beneath": in Haskell, the functions could be in any order in the source file.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A Haskell program's structure is surprisingly simple. You have a `main` function which does IO, and that's about it. So the basics:

```
module Main where

addition a b = a + b

main :: IO ()
main = do let z = addition 5 3
          putStrLn $ "The result is: " ++ show z
```

Now you can compile this into a simple program using something like:

```
ghc --make Main.hs -o program
```

and it should produce an executable called program.

In general, programs are structured as mostly pure functions doing the actual computation coupled with discrete parts of the code dealing with the IO. (There are of course exceptions to this, but the general idea of writing as much pure code as possible is fairly universal.)

Since almost everything is expressed as a bunch of pure functions, you do not pass variables between them--the functions communicate by passing arguments.

The part of your code that does `IO` is anchored in `main`. In most cases, *all* your IO is going to go through main; even if you write IO actions separately and give them names, they will ultimately be executed starting from `main`.

A "function group" in Haskell is called a "module". You can have multiple modules, each in its own file:

```
module Blarg (exportedFunction) where

helper a b = ... -- this will *not* be exported
exportedFunction a b = helper a b -- this *will* be exported
```

Only the identifiers in the parentheses will actually be exported; the rest are hidden. If you do not include the parentheses at all, everything will be exported by default.

Save this file as `Blarg.hs`. Now you can import it in `Main`:

```
import Blarg
```

Another useful way to group functions is `where`:

```
complicatedFunction a b c = helper 0
  where helper count = ...
```

This way `helper` is only in scope for `complicatedFunction` and also has access to `a`, `b` and `c` from `complicatedFunction`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm familiar with main, but how do I make other subroutines, and have those subroutines communicate and pass variables between each other?

Comment: You don't really have "subroutines", you have *functions*. Since there is no mutation, you pass values around as arguments to those functions (like `addition 5 3` in my example).

Comment: Right. I meant to say, how do you make other "function groups"? Basically, I'm trying not to put everything in main.

Comment: See this wiki page for information about Haskell Modules: http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: @dflemstr: That's not a wiki page, that's the Gentle Introduction :)

Comment: I see! I was using the wrong terminology, like "subroutine" and "data structure." What I wanted were "modules." Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: @ehird, that is very true, although I wish it was a wiki page, so much in fact that I managed to convince myself for a second!

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: You say "in most cases": in what cases do functions of type IO not go through `main`?

Comment: @amindfv: There is a function called `unsafePerformIO` which lets you do IO anywhere. However, it is (as the name unsubtly hints) *unsafe* and you should probably never need to use it. (It finds use in libraries like `System.Random`.)